# Mysql getting certian day's date with date range (syntax error)

Tags: mysql

This is my full code but when i start it,

```
DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME

SET @StartDateTime = '2022-04-01'
SET @EndDateTime = '2022-04-29';

WITH DateRange(Dates, DateWD) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDateTime as Date, DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @StartDateTime) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,Dates), DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(d,1,Dates)) 
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE Dates < @EndDateTime
)

SELECT Dates, DateWD
FROM DateRange 
 WHERE DATEWD NOT IN(1,7) AND Dates NOT IN(
 SELECT (HOLI_YEAR + '-' + HOLI_MONTH + '-' + HOLI_DAY) AS DATE
 FROM TB_HOLIDAY_CODE

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

This error cames out.

[image: image of error message]

I want to show 2022, april's date list except SUNDAY and SATURDAY

eg)  start date is 2022-04-01
end date is 2022-04-30

so result come out ->

| Dates | DateWD |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | (FRI) |
| 2022-04-04 | (MON) |
| 2022-04-05 | (TUE) |
| 2022-04-06 | (WED) |
| 2022-04-07 | (THU) |
| 2022-04-08 | (FRI) |
| 2022-04-11 | (MON) |
| .... | ... |

How can i fix this code? help me please. Thank you

*** I will not use table. Because i don't have table, and i want to use only SQL QUERY.

Comment: All SQL statements end in `;`. You don't need to `DECLARE` user variables (so omit those). What is `OPTION`? What MySQL version?

Comment: @danblack Thanks for your comment. MySQL's version is  8.0.28.  I just searched that query on internet and  i can't imagine what OPTION is.  https://aspdotnet.tistory.com/2258    this is site where i found the query.  If i omit DECLARE,    ```SET @StartDateTime = '2019-05-01';
SET @EndDateTime = '2019-05-08';```        should i use like this?

Comment: @sksmsWKd - That link shows a SQL Server example. `OPTION` doesn't apply to MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax error is because that example is written [for SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bfc51b7a2856d9a8a4be220ec9226eee), not MySQL. It needs a few adjustments to work with MySQL 8.x:

1. You don't need to `DECLARE` the [user defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html). Just use `SET` to both declare and assign the variable values
2. `DATEADD()` is a SQL Server function. The MySQL equivalent is [DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr unit)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)
3. `DATEPART(weekday,...)` is a SQL Server function. For MySQL, try [DAYOFWEEK(date)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek)
4. Lastly, use the keyword `RECURSIVE` with the CTE. From [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions):

> A common table expression is recursive if its subquery refers to its
> own name. The RECURSIVE keyword must be included if any CTE in the
> WITH clause is recursive.

**SQL**

```
SET @StartDateTime = '2022-04-01';
SET @EndDateTime = '2022-04-29';


WITH RECURSIVE DateRange(Dates, DateWD) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDateTime, DayOfWeek(@StartDateTime) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD(Dates, INTERVAL 1 DAY), DayOfWeek(DATE_ADD(Dates, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
    FROM  DateRange 
    WHERE Dates < @EndDateTime
)
SELECT * 
FROM   DateRange
WHERE  DateWDNOT IN(1,7)
```

**Result:**

| Dates | DateWD |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | 6 |
| 2022-04-04 | 2 |
| 2022-04-05 | 3 |
| 2022-04-06 | 4 |
| 2022-04-07 | 5 |
| 2022-04-08 | 6 |
| 2022-04-11 | 2 |
| 2022-04-12 | 3 |
| 2022-04-13 | 4 |
| 2022-04-14 | 5 |
| 2022-04-15 | 6 |
| 2022-04-18 | 2 |
| 2022-04-19 | 3 |
| 2022-04-20 | 4 |
| 2022-04-21 | 5 |
| 2022-04-22 | 6 |
| 2022-04-25 | 2 |
| 2022-04-26 | 3 |
| 2022-04-27 | 4 |
| 2022-04-28 | 5 |
| 2022-04-29 | 6 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2021e4abb4225510c48c290b78e10909)*

Comment: Thanks for your help. i had struggled for hours and you saved my time.